# « Un lecteur x » ou « le lecteur x »

Tags: grammaire, usage, articles, mathématiques

La présente question  n'est pas la mienne mais celle de user Oreste, qui l'a posée sur la page discussion « Chez Cosette » alors que c'est une question FSE normale. On en trouve les termes à partir de ces deux messages : [message 1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59201517#59201517), [message 2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59206984#59206984). Ils sont reproduits ci-dessous en ce qui concerne la question proprement dite.

> J'ai écrit :
> Maintenant, imaginez **un** lecteur X, sa routine (métro-boulot- enfants- paiements, etc.). Que voudrait-il lire : s'évader avec Harry Potter (par exemple) ou la description de vos problèmes ?
> Je me demande maintenant : est-ce que j'aurais dû écrire « **le** lecteur X » ou tout simplement sans article, « lecteur X » ?
> C'est très compliqué, je pensais qu'il était possible de parler du lecteur typique X, d'une manière générale.

Je pose cette question sur le FSE de façon à fournir une réponse détaillée et je l'éliminerai au cas où user Oreste tiendrait à la poser personnellement.

Answer (score 2):

1. (**Lecteur X**) La phrase originale est la suivante :

   > *Maintenant, imaginez **un lecteur X**, sa routine (métro-boulot- enfants- paiements, etc.). Que voudrait-il lire [...]*

   Ici, **X** a son sens mathématique représentant une donnée *inconnue*.

   Si on remplace X par l'adjectif inconnu, ça donne:

   > *Maintenant, imaginez **un** lecteur inconnu, sa routine [...]*

   *Un* est le bon article car ce lecteur étant inconnu, il n'est par défini. On ne met un article défini avec *inconnu* que s'il s'agit d'un inconnu particulier, on dit par exemple « la tombe **du** soldat inconnu » (c'est-à-dire celui-là et pas un autre).

2. (**Lecteur lambda**) Par la suite, il a été précisé que **lambda** avait été originellement envisagé à la place de **X**. Dans ce cas, la valeur est différente, *lambda* signifie quelconque, pris au hasard. **Un** et **le** sont ici tous deux possibles :

   2.1. **Un**

   > *Maintenant, imaginez **un** lecteur lambda, sa routine [...]*

   Ici, **un** peut avoir deux valeurs, celle d'article indéfini, **un** lecteur  indéfini parmi les autres, mais aussi parfois une valeur arithmétique, *imaginez **un** lecteur (pas **deux**)*.

   Exemple d'utilisation de l'article indéfini:

   > *Prenez l’affaire de Filippis. **Imaginez un lecteur lambda**, a priori choqué du traitement subi par votre confrère, mais qui, à la lecture de votre billet exposant le point de vue d’un commissaire, relativise la gravité de ce qui s’est passé, et nuance sa première approche, toute dictée par une émotion qui n’était nourrie d’aucune réflexion.* [La Plume d'Aliocha](https://laplumedaliocha.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/parachutes-dores-les-journalistes-derangent-et-cest-tant-mieux/), 2008

   2.2. **Le**

   > *Maintenant, imaginez **le** lecteur lambda, sa routine [...]*

   Ici, on a choisi un lecteur quelconque, l'archétype du lecteur banal et c'est de lui qu'on parle.

   Exemple d'utilisation de l'article défini:

   > *Faut se rendre compte que l'auteur de l'ouvrage pense parler à des adeptes d'histoire de l'art du XVIIIe, et que du coup, si déjà moi qui ai fait histoire de l'art, j'ai du mal, **imaginez le lecteur lambda**.* [Discussion Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:H%C3%B4tel_du_Ch%C3%A2telet/Bon_article), 2012

   Cette deuxième forme est probablement celle que j'aurais choisie.

Comment: Je vois la pomme sur la table. Je vois une pomme sur la table. C'est réponse me semble évidente. Cela dépend du vouloir-dire du locuteur.

Answer (score 1):

On dit en mathématiques [« fonction de la variable x »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fonction%20de%20la%20variable%20x%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) et aussi [« fonction d'une variable x »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foction+d%27une+variable+x%2Cfonction+de+la+variable+x&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfonction%20de%20la%20variable%20x%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfonction%20de%20la%20variable%20x%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

On remarque qu'en anglais on trouve aussi les deux, la tendance "the" étant plus forte ; cela correspond au français. ([the/a variable x](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=function+of+the+variable+x%2Cfunction+of+a+variable+x&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfunction%20of%20the%20variable%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfunction%20of%20a%20variable%20x%3B%2Cc0))

Il reste à savoir ce que l'usage courant doit à l'usage mathématique ; lorsque l'on parle de variable, en particulier lorsque'on dit « variable x », « variable y », etc., x est le nom de quelque chose que l'on admet ne pas définir sauf que x doit apartenir à une certaine catégorie, celle-ci étant par contre strictement définie avant ou tout de suite après la mention de « fonction de la variable x » (par exemple « fonction de la variable x , où x est un nombre naturel paire »). On voit donc que « variable » en tant que nom d'élément dans une certaine catégorie doit être associé à l'idée de référence générique et non de référence indéfinie, ceci étant parce qu'on parle de l'ensemble. Cet état de chose correspond à la fonction de référence générique que peuvent prendre l'article « le » (la, les) et « un » (une).

Dans ce cas de « lecteur x » il est apparent que l'on ne nomme pas un lecteur particulier de sorte à préserver son incognito, mais que l'on parle du lecteur « variable » (on le vois dans les précisions données par la suite : « lecteur typique X, d'une manière générale ») ; de plus, selon le principe mathématique, on nous décrit une catégorie à laquelle appartient ce lecteur variable : « navetteur, chargé de famille, soucis financiers ». On est donc confronté à l'usage mathématique de la variable et non à l'usage habituel d'attribution de faux nom, cas dans lequel, de toute façon, x n'est pas une variable mais pratiquement comme un nom.

On remarque que « variable x » se dirait tout aussi bien « élément x où x est variable » (bien que ce ne soit pas du tout  l'usage en mathématiques) et que cela correspond à « lecteur x où x est variable », et on peut conclure qu'on est en présence du même concept. On voit aussi que dans la langue courante x n'est pas absolument nécessaire, c'est un rafinement symbolique qui ne prend énormément d'intérêt qu'en mathématiques. On pourrait donc utiliser de façon similaire la formulation suivante.

- Imaginez le/un lecteur de petits moyens, sa routine (métro-boulot- enfants- paiements, etc.). Que voudrait-il lire : s'évader avec Harry Potter …

Il s'ensuit que soit « le » soit « un » pourrait être utilisé. « Le » semble cependant préférable.

Comment: un/le et a/the **dépend du vouloir-dire du locuteur ou rédacteur**.  Et ngrams ne prouvent rien dans un cas comme celui-ci.